# Fan noise and overheating problem in Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: 11.10, fan, overheating

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 in a Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop and it works fine. But I can hear a continuous noise from the cooling system. What should I do to solve this problem?